# Complex Analysis: $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} \int_0^1 f((1-t)z_0+tz) dt = f(z_0)$

Tags: complex-analysis

In class I encountered the following implicit claim:

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ open and $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ continuous. Moreover, let $z,z_0 \in U$. It holds:
>   $$\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} \int_0^1 f((1-t)z_0+tz) dt = f(z_0)$$

I do not see why we can exchange the limit and the integral here. Could you please explain?

Comment: It's only continuity.

Comment: But continuity alone does not imply that an exchange of an integral and a limit is allowed.

Comment: Are you aware of the dominated convergence theorem? I believe choosing a compact  and connected subset of $U$ and taking the limit inside it suffices if you use the boundedness of continuous functions on a compact set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuity of $f$ at $z_{0}$ gives for every $\epsilon>0$ some $\delta>0$ such that
\begin{align*}
|f(u)-f(z_{0})|<\epsilon,~~~~|u-z_{0}|<\delta.
\end{align*}
For all $t\in[0,1]$ and $|z-z_{0}|<\delta$, one has $|(1-t)z_{0}+tz-z_{0}|=t|z-z_{0}|\leq|z-z_{0}|<\delta$, so
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{0}^{1}f((1-t)z_{0}+tz)dt-f(z_{0})\right|&=\left|\int_{0}^{1}[f((1-t)z_{0}+tz)-f(z_{0})]dt\right|\\
&\leq\int_{0}^{1}|f((1-t)z_{0}+tz)-f(z_{0})|dt\\
&\leq\int_{0}^{1}\epsilon dt\\
&=\epsilon.
\end{align*}